# Confusing Bundles in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, bundle, bundle-product

Does anyone else find Magento bundles confusing?

It says like quantity 20 of 20 x single product even though you are only buying one bundle that contains 20 of a certain product.

Is this normal? It seems very confusing to me, is there a way to at least make this make more sense on the invoice?

See screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way things work for bundle products.
Bundles are just groups of simple products and you are making it easier for the customer to purchase them in the quantity needed.  Your example of the anise seeds are a perfect example.  This also allows you to control inventory, allow for discounts and other cart rules. Once you realize the power in that bundle product and how it works, you will be very happy.  Keep learning! Its just starting to get fun now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the bundles to group common ordering quantities of particular products. Or to create a 'build' item that has to be purchased from the manufacturer under different SKUs. It means that I can create a bundle with defined quantities so it makes it easier for the customer - https://www.westlab.com.au/gratnells-gratstack-treble-column-18-shallow-trays.